# Is there a way to handle node_modules in docker compose during git checkout?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

Docker is great while developing the app locally because it matches the production environment.

How I've seen it done:

### Mount the code

Mounting the host code folder inside the container allows editing the code and to instantly see the result inside the running docker container.

Normally `node_modules` are in `.gitignore`, meaning that `npm install` is required after building or if the `package.json` dependencies are changed.

For production it makes more sense to do `npm ci --production` in the Dockerfile using a multi-stage build, no `node_modules` folder on production.

Mounting the volume will replace all the code and add `node_modules` on the production ready image for development.

Pros:

- `node_modules` is not part of the Docker image (Smaller image)
- Rebuilding the dev container doesn't require re-downloading `node_modules` (`npm install` is faster)
- `npm install` is faster after the first time
- One Dockerfile for dev and production

Cons:

- `node_modules` on the host will be built for the docker OS (Not an issue if the container OS matches the host)
- May accidentally overwrite `node_modules` by doing `npm install` on the host (Not an issue if the OS matches the host)
- Need to `npm install` manually or automatically each time when rebuilding the dev container (For example `docker-compose` could run `npm install`) or possibly manually when changing branches.
- Need to connect the IDE interpreter to the container (might be ok to use the host `node_modules`).

### Work remotely

`git clone main` and `npm ci --production` inside the `Dockerfile` and do [remote development using vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) (or any other IDE that supports that)

Then while developing inside the container do `npm install` manually to get the devDependencies

Pros:

- Developing inside an environment that matches production
- `node_modules` is not part of the Docker image (Smaller image)
- One Dockerfile for dev and production

Cons:

- Everyone on the team has to use an IDE that supports remote development
- Changes are lost each time after rebuilding the container. (`git commit` makes this ok)
- Need to `npm install` manually or automatically each time when rebuilding the dev container (For example `docker-compose` could run `npm install`) or possibly manually when changing branches.

### Mount the code without `node_modules`

Same as "Mount the code" above, but using a hack with an additional mount volume to avoid having `node_modules` on the OS

```sh
docker volume create node_modules
```

in `docker-compose.yml`

```
myapp:
    volumes:
        - /me/code:/app
        - node_modules:/app/node_modules

volumes:
    node_modules:
```

Or move `node_modules` to be outside of `/app`

Pros:

- `node_modules` is not part of the Docker image (Smaller image)
- Rebuilding the dev container doesn't require re-downloading `node_modules` (`npm install` is faster), only required after the `node_modules` volume is removed.
- One Dockerfile for dev and production

Cons:

- Need to `npm install` manually or automatically each time you rebuild the dev container (For example `docker-compose` could run `npm install`) or possibly manually when changing branches.
- Need to connect the IDE interpreter to the container (or do `npm install` on the host, which won't necessarily match the one on the container and cause bugs).

### Or some other way that I haven't mentioned.

---

Each way assumes that we boot using `CMD dumb-init node server.js`.

The problem is that if there is a `git checkout` to a different branch with new dependencies in `package.json` the app startup may fail during `docker-compose up`, stopping the container.

It is annoying having to go bug hunting when such a common thing happens.

One solution is to run `npm install` just before `dumb-init node server.js`, but this doesn't seem like the best approach.

Is there an automated way to handle the change in `package.json` during development for the ways mentioned above?

Comment: "And which way is considered the standard proper way and why?" - careful. You should not ask multiple questions, especially if they start to sound dangerously close to being opinionated. Nobody here can or should dictate what the standard proper way is, you will have to make up your own mind based on your own development environment. For example, you list as a con "Everyone on the team has to use an IDE that supports remote development". Your opinion that it is a con, quite some people will state it is a good idea everyone uses the same tooling. Who's correct?

Comment: @Gimby good point, do you have any suggestions on how to improve the question? I kind of assumed there was one proper way and I'm just oblivious to it.

Comment: IME, Node isn't so fragile that it's important your development environment _precisely_ matches production.  If you're using a bind-mount to replace all of the code with local files, then you're really just running local code over a `node` image; and if you're doing that, why not use Node directly on the host without Docker?